# Mysql query running very slow with sum and group by option

Tags: mysql

Mysql query running very slow.
there are 1000000 rows in the table.I have added explain query to the question. it is taking 10-11 seconds. I have multiple conditions which keep on changing basis user's input. Is it possible to provide unique index.
explain query
id              -1  
select_type     -SIMPLE 
table           -sellers 
type            -ref 
possible_keys   -quarter,quarter_2,comp_idx1,index_all,qc 
key             -qc 
key_len         -32 
ref             -const 
rows            -399782 
Extra           -Using where

```
SELECT `cm`, 
       `week`, 
       `quarter`,
       SUM( `gmv`) as gmv, 
       SUM( `qty_sold`) as qty_sold, 
       SUM( `live_listing`) as live_listing , 
       SUM( `txn`) as txn, 
       SUM( `new_listings`) as new_listings, 
       SUM( `ended_listings`) as ended_listings 
FROM `sellers` 
where quarter=:quarter and 
      category=:category 
group by cm

CREATE TABLE `sellers` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `seller_id` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 `am` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
 `rm` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
 `cm` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
 `week` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
 `quarter` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
 `site` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 `category` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 `format` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 `price_band` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 `gmv` double(11,2) NOT NULL,
 `qty_sold` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `live_listing` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `txn` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `new_listings` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `ended_listings` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `seller_id` (`seller_id`),
 KEY `quarter` (`quarter`),
 KEY `week` (`week`),
 KEY `id` (`id`),
 KEY `category` (`category`),
 KEY `site` (`site`),
 KEY `cm` (`cm`),
 KEY `rm` (`rm`),
 KEY `am` (`am`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1692618 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: What is the definition of "very slow" ? How much time is it taking currently ? Also, add `EXPLAIN` statement result to the question for the current query.

Comment: Please add these details to the question, by editing it. All the formatting is lost in the comments and make it unreadable.

Comment: use order by null after group byu statement

Comment: Generally, you should include within a GROUP BY any and all non-aggregated columns within the SELECT

Comment: @Strawberry I didn't get that.

Comment: Your SELECT includes cm, week, and quarter, but your GROUP BY does not.

Comment: @strawberry will there be any impact on the performance?

Answer (score 0):

You can add an index to 'cm' column. It will be faster than previously

Answer (score 0):

In a particular query, MySQL is able to use only one index at a time. In your case, you have multiple columns to check against. You will need to add a Composite Index on `(quarter, category, cm)`, for better performance:

```
ALTER TABLE sellers 
ADD INDEX comp_idx1(quarter, category, cm);
```

Comment: It fails if I remove category condition. we have various (5-6) parameter to put in the condition. I have added one more index after removing category from the filter. ALTER TABLE sellers ADD INDEX qc(quarter, cm) 
still it is not working.

Comment: @ManishMalviya what do you mean by "its not working" ? Please specify the duration for which queries are running ? Add `EXPLAIN` statement results to the question so that it can be analyzed further.

Comment: Explain sql results. and query taking 10 sec.

id -                1
select_type -SIMPLE
table           sellers
type                   ref
possible_keys   quarter,quarter_2,comp_idx1,index_all,qc
key                   qc
key_len           32
ref                   const
rows           399782
Extra Using where

Comment: @dwir182 Added.

Comment: I think sum function is taking much time.

Comment: @ManishMalviya yes it will. because to sum the values, it cannot use index. It will have to scan each and every row, to add them